# Garment Digitization in Blender

Tags: add-on, cloth-simulation

Hey Blender Community!

We at [TRI3D](http://tri3d.in/) at developing virtual dressing room technology. Currently we are using blender's cloth simulator as a test bed. The results have been very encouraging. Have a look at the [simulation video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0DuLe3SEAM) to get an idea about the simulation quality.

There are two parts to the problem , garment digitisation and cloth simulation. We would want to open source the garment digitisation work which we would want to implement as an add-on.

To start off things we [hosted the code on bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/nitish_116/tri3d_gazer/), and also made [addon installation and usage videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rSOrc_rPAnM).

We would want to have Marvellous Designer like features for the blender cloth simulator to create the garments in an intuitive way.

How this add-on will help ?

1. Model the Garment Outline, Meshing will be taken care by 'meshpy'
2. Sewing Springs and Positions of Patterns can be saved and reused.
3. Can handle multiple garments and multiple patterns inside it.

Issues:

1. Currently we are not providing it as an add-on zip, source code is
   available on bitbucket

   2 . Requires meshpy to be installed in blender python site-packages

We have lot of features planned up. But before diving further we want to make sure the framework is right. We are really new to blender scripting and would want to make sure we are not committing any beginner mistakes. Hoping the community will support us in this project!

Comment: Have you seen the [gerber tech](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=te9an_-fWTU&index=6&list=PLa1F2ddGya__l2Tk4zzq8c6CNGPCjQaS4) conference talk?

Comment: Hey @sambler, We did check Richard's Work. Our addon is focussed on generating the garment patterns quickly so that the manual effort for modelling can be reduced.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question.

Answer (score 0):

So what is the question really? Can you add a phrase ending in a question mark to your post.

This all sounds like excellent progress and great news for the Blender community in general, unfortunately this seems like the wrong place to post this sort of work.

If **you want user level feedback** you should probably post this in the [Blender Artists Forum](https://blenderartists.org) where it will probably gather a lot more attention and feedback.

If you are looking for **developer feedback** or a way to get this merged or approved into official blender then you should probably contact the developers, possibly through the [bf committers mailing list](https://lists.blender.org/mailman/listinfo/bf-committers). Developers don't come here often if at all.

As far as I know there are [currently developments efforts already being made](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?403880-Cloth-simulator-improvements) for the cloth simulation area, and general physics simulation improvements targeted for the great upcoming Blender 2.8 revamp.

It would probably be beneficial if your work aligned well with the upcoming changes, and possibly take advantage of them.

Maybe you can even contribute your knowledge or skills to help in the improvement of the new features.

Maybe also contact Luca Rood, who appears to be in charge of this area so we can mutually benefit from it

Comment: Hey, We are new to this whole ecosystem. We posted on few blender forums. What we were actually looking for was developer feedback and visibility in developers working actively. Like you mentioned We will reach out to bf commiters and Luca Rood. This was an honest mistake!

Comment: No problem, glad to help, and best of luck with this work, looks super useful, even though I don't use cloth simulations often.